# Predict values from random forest model

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to run a random forest model with the following code:

```
rftest <- randomForest(as.numeric(depn)~., data=for.rf, na.action=na.omit, 
                       importance=T, ntree=1000)
```

`depn` is the dependent variables and `for.rf` contains the set of dependent and independent variables. Next I am trying to predict the values using
`predict(rftest,for.rf)` and then manually I calculated the mean of squared residuals which didn't match the RF output. However simply using `predict(rftest)` match the results. Can you help me to understand how `predict(rftest,for.rf)` behaves differently than `predict(rftest)`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the help page `?predict.randomForest` we see:

> **newdata** a data frame or matrix containing new data.
>   (Note: If not given, the out-of-bag prediction in object is returned.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-bag_error) says:

> OOB is the mean prediction error on each training sample xᵢ,  using
>   only the trees that did not have xᵢ in their bootstrap sample.

So your first calculation, `predict(rftest)`, is the out-of-bag prediction whereas your second calculation, `predict(rftest, for.rf)`, is the result of the full-prediction model on the training data.